# How can I logout form one account and authorize my jupyter notebook to another google account for BigQuery [my_df.to_gbq()]?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I just authorized my python notebook to one of google big query accounts to inject data to a bigquery table [my_df.to_gbq()]. Now I want to inject data to another table which belong to another google account. But when I am using my_df.to_gbq() its looking for the projects and tables of my previous account. How can I logout form that account and authorize my notebook for new google account?

403 error: Access Denied: Table toyota-bi:intern_data_archive.sales: Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table toyota-bi:intern_data_archive.sales (or it may not exist)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to remove *pandas-gbq* from your *third party app* list of your Google account.

1. Go to [`https://myaccount.google.com/security`](https://myaccount.google.com/security)
2. Check what are the third party apps that you have authorized from your Google
   account.
3. Remove *pandas-gbq*
4. Run `my_df.to_gbq()`

At this time your code will ask you to authorize your account again.